# FractionallySizedCircle? in flutter

Tags: flutter

is there any tricks to achieve sth like a FractionallySizedBox 
to get a circle the size of a fraction of parent's height or width ?
like this :

```
FractionallySizedCircle(
  heightFactor: .5,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2000), // side question : is there a better way to achieve this too ?
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: globals.lightBlue,
      ),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 1),
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/images/boy-id.svg'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[Update] : I needed to have a circular ClipRRect just like the sample code has the ClipRRect in it, changed it with clipOval and did the job, but would come in handy if we could have real `FractionallySizedCircle` (this ClipOval is actually an oval obviuosly), so the question stays open...

Answer (score 0):

You can use FractionallySizedBox and Container simply like this:

```
FractionallySizedBox(
  heightFactor: 0.5,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: the purpose was actually a real circle , not to make the container look circular , clipping the children is important here. sample code you provided is actually part of the question itself. :hearts